elasticsearch - reindex only specified data in field
I'm working with reindex but only with specified data in field.
I have field "plugin" and  I need to create index from only part of "docplugin"
I created query and it is running well :


GET dataindex/_search
{   "query":
{ "match":
{ "plugin": "docplugin"
}
},
"fields": [ "plugin" ] }


I created reindex with that search and I'm failed on that:


POST _reindex {    "source": {
"dataindex": "app-2024.08.01"   "query": {
"match": {
"plugin": "docplugin"
}    },
"fields": [
"plugin" ]   },     "dest": { "index": "metric123"    },***

}

Looks like reindex with that search is not working.

Problem here is that the reindex API doesn’t support the fields parameter. You’ll need to use the _source parameter to include only the specific fields you want.
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "app-2024.08.01",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "plugin": "docplugin"
      }
    },
    "_source": ["plugin"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "metric123"
  }
}

